# Are armouries, weapons and the Bat in "Dark Knight rises" attainable by current technologies?

Tags: dc, batman, technology, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

Batman has a lot of fanciful armouries and weapons and the Bat in "Dark Knight rises". Are all these attainable by current technologies? If yes, how much it will cost to be a Batman in the movie?

Comment: These might be helpful: http://www.centives.net/S/2012/how-much-does-it-cost-to-be-batman/ http://www.geekologie.com/2012/07/682-million-the-real-cost-of-being-batma.php

Comment: This discovery channel points explains some of the science behind Batman's gadgets: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BXPOENATC8

Comment: This question seems salvageable to me.  It wouldn't invalidate the existing answers to edit it to say "How much would it cost to become Batman".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Is it possible to be Batman? Certainly some of the technology exists, but putting it together in a way that can be used the way the Batman does is another matter. Using today's technologies and cutting edge designs, the cost of being Batman is estimated at $682,450,750. This takes into account his suit, vehicles, training, equipment, mansion and manservant. And if you're willing to do without the Batcave-Mansion combination, you can do it on a shoe-string of $83 million.**

### **The Suit**

- Made from cutting-edge Nomex materials, it's insulating padding, fire-resistant and bullet-proof against small arms. Wouldn't want to get hit with any [7.62 Nato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7.62%C3%9751mm_NATO) rounds, though.
- Covered in armored plates and ribs for articulation and ease of movement, make the suit capable of being reasonably capable of a high degree of mobility. He would have to spend quite a bit of time training with it to learn where the blind spots were, where mobility issues might affect his fighting style and knowing how to best keep the enemy where he has maximum fighting capacity.
- The suit also armors the most vulnerable spots shoulders, knees, elbows, shins, and forearms. The chest also has a heavy plate in the center of mass zone people are taught to aim at.
- The cape is made of a [memory cloth polymer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape-memory_polymer) capable of being used as a makeshift paraglider or parachute.
- A suit of armor including a custom fitted graphite bullet resistant cowl could run you about: $1,058,600. Believe it or not most of the cost of that suit is the hardened, padded, custom fitted cowl.

[image: The Bat-suit]

### **The Vehicles**

- The Tumbler was developed for Wayne Enterprises Applied Sciences Division as a military bridging vehicle. Covered in weapons and capable of stealth mode operations, each unit cost a cool $18,000,000.
- The Batpod, a motorcycle-like vehicle which acts as an escape vehicle from a burning Tumbler has 20" wheels, and is capable of making a 90 degree turn almost instantly by rotating its wheels on any axis. (Don't ask me how, I'm still mentally working it out.) Steered by shoulder movements allowing for hands-free driving, it's cheap at $1,500,000.
- The coolest of the Batman's vehicles shows up in the Dark Knight Rises, and is called The Bat. A hovering, harrier-like vehicle capable of VTOL, fast flight and  acceleration, and as nimble as a helicopter in tight quarters. There is nothing like it in real life but an estimated cost was $60,000,000.

### **"The Most Wonderful Toys"**

- There are so many gadgets, I am going to let the graphic speak for itself. Suffice it to say a night on the Bat-town means he leaves home with $400,000 worth of untraceable Bat-paraphernalia.

[image]

### **Stately Wayne Manor**

- This is where the biggest cost of being Batman is incurred. Rebuilding the mansion, its grounds, increasing security, hollowing out and reinforcing the Batcave, replacing the supercomputer, rebuilding his private forensic labs, gun ranges, Bat supply kits, medical facilities, the turnabout, extra cars, the silencing of the workers (hopefully with cash incentives, not the other kind) comes in at a cool $600,000,000. Sorry, still blinking at that number. That does not include the stately Wayne manservant's fees as both butler and major domo for the estate, another $240,000 annually.
- And if we assume he paid for training and the equivalent of a Doctorate in something or another, plus an engineering degree or two, throwing in military pilot training, to fly the Bat and anything else with wings, firearms training and military knowledge to be able to use all of his ordinance, we are looking at $1, 750,000 dollars worth of education.

*The source of all of this information was MoneySuperMarket.com and Warner Brothers and DC Comics provided the images.* You can check out the complete graphic [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VCuy.jpg).

Comment: I might contend that the motorcycle is the coolest mode of bat-transportation. I was reasonably convinced by the turnaround in The Dark Knight after nearly flattening the Joker, but once we got Anne Hathaway on that thing, no question for me.

Comment: Um, Thaddeus?  Were you just mentioned on *Adult Swim*?  And did they cite this very answer in the bump that mentioned you?

Comment: You're on TV! https://youtu.be/a4MprjNu-mg

Comment: I'd be willing to spend as much as the Cowl on the groin armor, though.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the production crew actually built The Tumbler for the first film (see the DVD extras), so yes to that.  It drove pretty well too.  I doubt the computer AI in it is achievable yet though.

Not sure about the rest.

Comment: They built a working prototype for the movie, but obviously it couldn't jump or do any of many things the tumbler is  seen doing in the movie. I think that those DVD extras show the giant ramp the had to use to simulate its jumps, to film the landing scenes. It seemed to be a pretty sturdy car, nevertheless.