# Problem with Batmobile's (Batman begins) driver switching positions

Tags: dc, batman

In Batman begins we saw how the pilot/driver of the tumbler can switch to a prone position for better control or the vehicle weapondry. http://www.deviantart.com/art/NEW-BATMOBILE-DESIGNS-19640136

[image]

Wouldn't this movement hurt Batman's legs? Would this position switch be possible at all?

Also, Batman asked Gordon "Can you drive stick" when requesting his help driving the batmobile. Even leaving this as a joke or catchy line, and supposing the tumbler can be driven as an automatic car, you still need to step on gas or brakes, which is unclear how can be done from that position.

So, is this shifting positions system possible (or just if we suspend disbelief?).

To clarify I'm asking if is really possible or reasonable switching to the prone position as seen in the movie without hurting the driver and then being able to control the vehicle.

Comment: I'm not sure what can be added beyond what's already in your own picture. It clearly shows that he can move into that position and it shows that the steering wheel controls the speed.

Comment: The answer to this question is both plausible and able to be explained. I have an answer for it. The problem lies in the diagrams used to explain what happened. Those are fan diagrams and they are incorrect.

Comment: @Richard, thanks for the edit, the link is more clear now. Despite that picture, I am not sure if that is possible at all, given the space in the cockpit and the kind of movement needed to switch positions (Nolan movies are supposed to be "realistic". Think about Batman legs, his cape, a possible safety belt, distance to the dashboard and height of the cockpit rooftop). Besides, how do you brake or accelerate when in that position?

Comment: @thaddeus - It doesn't appear to be fanart. The LA Times credits it as being an original piece by Nathan Crowley, Production Artist for Batman Begins; http://www.chickslovethecar.com/images/uploaded/612200523719tumblerlatimes4yz4pc.jpg

Comment: @Thaddeus, Thanks, I didn't know that it was fan art not "unofficial". My problem with it is that I will believe that the Tumbler is supper fast, highly manuverable and that jumps off rooftops, but that thingy switching positions is highly dubious to me. I wanted to know if by any means that could be possible or if it was just a regular "its a film, make it look cool".

Comment: I fail to see how these edits make it any less opinion-based. Clearly he can switch positions and control the vehicle because **we see him doing it**. If you're looking for an out-of-universe explanation, then this needs to be raised on another stack.

Comment: How does he control it? At least about the batpod it is said that is controlled with the shoulders, since the arms and hands are used for the weapons. I don't think that you can reach the third position of that diagram without actually falling to the floor. Does the rest of the seat follow batman when he switch positions like that (safety belt). What about pedals, where do they go? I actually thought that the answer in other stacks would had been "Its a movie. Suspend disbelief". I asked here because I thought I could get an explanation consistent with the "Nolanverse", but OK, leave as it is.

Comment: Who says the thing does not contain rudimentary AI that helps it being driven / or even drive itself. Micheal Keaton's could do it way back when...

Comment: Advanced systems or AI could assist for jumps, aiming, maneuvering or even keeping the driver stable when jumping, but AI can't know when you want to stop, only when you NEED to stop/decelerate. Nevertheless, I think is a great explanation that an auto-pilot would drive the car while the driver is in the second position, focused on the weapons. I think that the vehicles in Dark Knight Rises have actually a driver and a artillerist.

Comment: @Thaddeus, I have the Dark Knight Manual (which is awesome) but I couldn't find info about this. If you know of other diagrams or sources that could further explain the Tumbler/Batmovile could you point me to them, please? Thanks.

Comment: This is a related question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21119/are-armouries-weapons-and-the-bat-in-dark-knight-rises-attainable-by-current Why is my question about if the position switch is attainable considered not appropriate for the SciFi stack?

Comment: @deion - Good point. I've flagged that one as well.

Comment: @Richard, but that question was asked and answered (with 17 and 20 votes, respectively, so I guess people liked or found useful both question and answer) two years ago. Why would it be considered wrong now?

Comment: @Deion - Just because a question is old (or has attracted upvotes) doesn't mean that it falls within the rules of the site. Closing a question isn't a personal judgment on the OP, it's just a friendly way of asking the OP to rewrite it in a way that fits the rules. When you start taking things personally, that's when problems occur.

Comment: @Richard, I don't take it personal, even if my reputation is going up and down and my question losing the votes it had. Is not that, if you can believe it. All the process was weird to me, because I failed to see the reasons you so clearly pointed to me in the chat. I checked other questions tagged with "batman" before asking mine, to check for duplicates of my question and the like. I saw that one and asked something that way, then I was told I was not doing properly, and that what I was using as a reference should have been banned long time ago to... I thank you for your work as OP (honest)

Comment: Regarding plausible acceleration and braking while in such a position: the [Hy-wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Motors_Hy-wire) car has both integrated into the wheel. Pedals optional.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Yes, given the parameters of the Tumbler as designed, the vehicle could support multiple configurations by using controls built into the movable steering column. While the prone position is likely to be uncomfortable, it is completely machine controlled, padded and balanced by a gyroscopic system and likely not meant to be used for long periods of time.

- We can assume Batman is wearing a seatbelt capable of supporting his own weight. This aids in stability, restricting unwanted movement.
- In the sequence where Batman goes into the weapon's well, he is not flipped forward. He slides into position and leans forward onto a platform designed to support his chest and legs.

The slide activation sequence starts at 1:30.

- He inches forward and slides into position. I suspect it is designed to give him support on his knees and allow him to press his feet against the back for leverage and control of the steering.
- His knees are likely hanging free like they might in a low riding motorcycle. He is more likely pressing his feet against the back of the vehicle offering stability while maneuvering.
- The headrest presses against his back helping to hold him in place.

[image]

This padded and gyroscopic system provides him with shock absorption, and ensures even if the vehicle is at an angle other than flat, he maintains his position within the Tumbler. Note the rotation while the Tumbler is on the angled roof.

[image]

The system seems elaborate but plausible.

- I suspect Batman is joking about someone else driving the vehicle since the control system is in his hands the entire time. Nor does the vehicle seem to have a standard control interface of pedals given its need for multiple configuration modes.
- Could the car be driven by autopilot? Given of what we have seen of Batmobiles in the past, the vehicle's limited AI could probably navigate the streets of Gotham, even if Batman was unconscious.

Comment: Good answer. Bad question

Comment: Given the opening sequence in the Dark Knight with the "Loiter/Intimidate" programs, no doubt the Tumbler already has preset programs for limited movements.

Comment: @Richard, Why? Why you keep saying that? You edited my question yourself, and also put it on hold. Thaddeus said already on comment #2 that he understood the question and could explain this whole sequence, which is what I wanted, and is what he has done. You didn't consider this question worth it, saying that is was possible because the movie showed it and could be done just as the movie showed it. I even compared it to similar questions, yet I fail to see why is is considered bad. Can't be unclear, since Thaddeus got it. Could you please elaborate so I improve my questions in the future?thnks

Comment: @Deion - I'm happy to chat with you about it; http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16863/batmobilechat

Comment: BTW, Thaddeus was also right the Batman **slides** into the weapons well, and does not get lifted up or moved forward, as shown in the diagram of the question's link.